# What is the inverse Laplace transform of $sF''(s)$?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, laplace-transform

I need to find the inverse Laplace transform of $sF''(s)$ where $F(s) = \int_0^\infty f(t)e^{-st}dt$. This is not one of the cases in my book. What can I do to compute this?

My hunch is that the answer is $t^2f'(t)$ seen in the beginning of this paper.

https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007/PL00001481.pdf

In this paper, they inverse laplace transform

$$
w^{i v}-10 z w^{\prime \prime}-10 w^{\prime}+9 z^2 w=0
$$

into $$
9 f^{\prime \prime}-10 t^2 f^{\prime}+\left(t^4-10 t\right) f=0
$$

where $$
w(z)=\int_{\mathcal{C}} f(t) e^{-z t} d t
$$

The only term that I cannot compute from the Laplace transform table is the $zw''(z)$ term, but according to this table, it should be $tf'(t)$

Thank you

Comment: Do you have any ideas?

Comment: My hunch is $s^2f'$ which was done here https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007/PL00001481.pdf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\begin{split}
\mathcal{L}^{-1}\{sF''(s)\} &= \mathcal{L}^{-1}\{sF''(s) + F'(s)\} - \mathcal{L}^{-1}\{F'(s)\}\\
&= \mathcal{L}^{-1}\{\frac{d}{ds}(sF'(s))\} + tf(t)\\
&= -t\mathcal{L}^{-1}\{sF'(s)\}(t) + tf(t)\\
&= -t[\mathcal{L}^{-1}\{sF'(s) + F(s)\} - \mathcal{L}^{-1}\{F(s)\}](t) + tf(t)\\
&= -t\mathcal{L}^{-1}\{\frac{d}{ds}(sF(s))\}(t) + 2tf(t)\\
&= t^2\mathcal{L}^{-1}\{sF(s)\}(t) + 2tf(t)\\
&= t^2[\mathcal{L}^{-1}\{sF(s) - f(0)\} + \mathcal{L}^{-1}\{f(0)\}](t) + 2tf(t)\\
&= t^2f'(t) + t^2f(0)\delta(t) + 2tf(t)\\
&= t^2f'(t) + 2tf(t)
\end{split}$$