# Off by a negative sign in Laplace transform $\mathcal{L}\{tx^{(3)}(t)\}(s)$?

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, analysis, laplace-transform

Let $f(s) = \mathcal{L} \{ x(t) \}(s).$
Then

$$\mathcal{L}\{tx^{(3)}(t)\}(s)=-1\frac{d}{dx}\mathcal{L}\{x^{(3)}(t)\}(s)=-\frac{d}{ds}[s^2f(s)]=-[2sf(s)+s^2f'(s)]$$

using the identities

$$
f^{\prime}(t) \quad s F(s)-f(0)
$$

and
$$
t^n f(t), \quad n=1,2,3, \ldots \quad(-1)^n F^{(n)}(s).
$$

Should the minus sign actually be there?

In `https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4886992/what-is-the-inverse-laplace-transform-of-sfs`, it was computed that

$$\mathcal{L}^{-1}\left\{s F^{\prime \prime}(s)\right\}=t^2 f^{\prime}(t)+2 t f(t)$$

which does not have a negative sign. Is this correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using differentiation under the integral and integration by parts three times, we have

$$\begin{align}
\int_0^\infty t x'''(t) e^{-st}\,dt&=-\frac{d}{ds}\int_0^\infty x'''(t) e^{-st}\,dt\\\\
&=-\frac{d}{ds}\left(s^3X(s)-\sum_{n=1}^3 s^{3-n}x^{(n-1)}(0)\right)\\\\
&=-3s^2X(s)-s^3X'(s)+2sx''(0)+x'(0)
\end{align}$$

If $x(0)=x'(0)=0$ then we have

$$\int_0^\infty t x'''(t) e^{-st}\,dt=-3s^2X(s)-s^3X'(s)$$

Comment: Great I did it correctly :) Thank you!

Comment: You're welcome.   My pleasure.